# Data Model from MySQL to mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have the following 3 tables in MySQL(RDBMS)

```
 CREATE TABLE user
 (
  id INTEGER,
  username VARCHAR(20)
 )

 CREATE TABLE bank_account
 (
 id INTEGER,
 bankid INTEGER(FK to BANK),
 uid INTEGER(FK to USER),
 acc_number INTEGER
 )

 CREATE TABLE bank
 (
  bankid INTEGER,
  bank_name VARCHAR(50),
 )
```

There are like more than 1 million rows in the user table.

What I want to do is to model this in MongoDB something like this:

```
  db.createCollection("user")
  db.user.insert([
  id: 12345,
  username: 'user1'
  bank: [
 {
  bankid: 100,
  bank_name: 'take bank',
  acc_number: 345
  }]
  ])
```

I have extracted the data from each table in json. 
The problem is how do I store the three tables in mongodb with embedding like above? Is there a tool which can do this? Or I write an algorithm in python or some other language?

Answer (score 0):

You can create this dataset using mongo shell which supports javascript.

You can do this in python as well.

This [tool](https://github.com/feliixx/mgodatagen) is one the easy tool to generate datasets in mongodb.

You can download it [here](https://github.com/feliixx/mgodatagen/releases)

Comment: Well, I am new to mongodb.

Comment: I don't want to generate json. I already have the data extracted. I want to model it the other way. Like I gave the example